# Installing Ubuntu server alongside Ubuntu Desktop 14.04.1 LTS

Tags: dual-boot

My current configuration:

1. **Dual boot with GRUB for Win 7 and Ubuntu Desktop 14.04.1 LTS**. Running fine with options to got Win 7 or Ubuntu.
2. **Installed Ubuntu Studio after this**. Running fine with option to go to desktop / Studio after selecting Ubuntu after Step 1 above.
3. I now want to install Ubuntu Server on the same machine alongside the existing set up.
4. Would it be possible to get an option on booting up to select from Win 7/ Ubuntu desktop / Ubuntu Server? Alternatively is it possible to get option to choose from Ubuntu Desktop / Ubuntu Server /Ubuntu Studio ?

Please help me out with this task.

Regards and best wishes.

Sunil

Comment: Should be the same as installing any other Ubuntu, should work. But Ubuntu server is basically regular Ubuntu, without any desktop/GUI stuff

Comment: Thank you. The aim was to 1. check if i can add another version of ubuntu after desktop and Studio and then get the choice on booting into Ubuntu to select any of the three versions. 2. Understand the installation procedure and then the capabilities of Ubuntu server.

Answer (score 1):

Once you are dualbooting adding another install should be straightforward. Ubuntu server shouldn't be any different in terms of installing to the versions you have already installed.

All entries should show up on the grub menu.

Comment: Thank you. The aim was to 1. check if i can add another version of ubuntu after desktop and Studio and then get the choice on booting into Ubuntu to select any of the three versions. 2. Understand the installation procedure and then the capabilities of Ubuntu server.

Comment: So as per you if i was to install from Ubuntu Server CD i will be able to use all three variants of Ubuntu - Desktop/Studio/Server as per my requirement. Would there be any issues with the partitioning or would it be handled automatically. In the earlier case, when i had installed Studio after the DEsktop the tasks were handled automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have some compelling reason to have a seperate server install, why not just install the required packages in your desktop/ubuntu studio install? Why not just keep your ubuntu studio install (for the lower latency kernel and jack setup),delete your ubuntu install, then just install the packages you use in the studio install?

Comment: Thank you. I have already installed MySQL and Apache on the DEsktop version. Primarily this exercise was to check if the three Ubuntu versions can be installed and also to examine the capabilities/packages of Ubuntu Sever.